# How to invoke methods of hooked class within aspect?

Tags: java, hook, aop, aspectj

Maybe name of theme is bad. I try to explain clarity.

I have class:

```
public class A(){
   Field1 field1;
   Field2 field2;
   public void method1(){...}
   public void method2(){...}
   public void sourceMethod(ParameterClass parameter1){
     //some code
     method1();
     //some code
      method2();
     //some cdoe
  }
}
```

I will hook source method:
...

```
@Around(value = "execution(* A.sourceMethod(ParameterClass))")
    public void aroundSourceMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint){
      //I need to write my realization sourceMethod here
      // I want to invoke method1 and method2 here
}
```

Here I want to rewrite all code. But I need to invoke `method1()` and `method2()`

Is it possibly using AspectJ ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to execute the methods `method1()` and `method2()` before the `sourceMethod()` is called? By writing an `@Around` advice? Why not use the `@Before` in that case. Also, aspectJ will just provide an intercepting mechanism. the invocation has to happen through reflection. That is nothing to do with AspectJ

Comment: this method was written bad. I need to rewrite it fully

Comment: But if you are writing an aspect around the method, that is not going to escape from the method not executing. you might just end up executing the `method1()` and `method2()` twice. Because, your program is actually going to enter `sourceMethod()` even with the aspect weaved into your program.

Comment: if I understood you right...I will not execute *proceed* method inside my @Around aspect

Comment: yeah thats correct, but its a hack. :)

Comment: I don't see another ways to rewrite logic inside .class files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Around(value = "execution(* A.sourceMethod(Parameter)) && target(target)")
public void aroundSourceMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object target){
   // I need to write my realization sourceMethod here
   // I want to invoke method1 and method2 here
}
```

Target will contain the object which sourceMethod is executed on. Since you only advise A.sourceMethod(), you can assume that it is of type A, cast it to that and call its methods as you like:

```
((A) target).method1()
...
```

It's not pretty, but it should work.